# New search form partial is redirecting to my main index page for the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have an events model and I have an address field where I have some geolocation logic being implemented. On my main index page, I'm rendering a search form partial that works just fine to be all to search all of the events in my database.

Here's the original search form:

```html
<%= search_form_for @q,  
    data: { controller: "places", action: "google-maps-callback@window->places#initMap" } do |f| %>
    <div class="formlook">
        <div class="event-search-container">
            <div class="event-name">
                <%= f.label "Event name", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.search_field :name_cont, placeholder: "Any event", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="geolocation">
                <%= f.label "Geolocation", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.search_field :address_or_city_or_state_or_country_or_continent_cont_all, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search by continent, country, state, or city", data: { places_target: "field" } %>
            </div>
            <div class="dancestyle">
                <%= f.label "Dance style", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.select(:dance_styles_id_in, DanceStyle.all.pluck(:name, :id), { :include_blank => "All dance styles" }, { class: "form-select", id: "select-dancestyle", multiple: true, placeholder: "Any dance style" }) %>
            </div>
            <div class="eventtype">
                <%= f.label "Event Type", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.select :event_type_id_in, EventType.all.pluck(:name, :id), { :include_blank => "All event types" }, { id: "select-artist", multiple: true, placeholder: "Any event type", class: "form-select" } %>
            </div>
            <div class="month">
                <%= f.label "Month", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.select(:event_month_in, (Date::MONTHNAMES[1..12]), { prompt: "Any month" }, { id: "select-month", :include_blank => "Any month", class: "form-select", multiple: true }) %>
            </div>
            <div class="year">
                <%= f.label "Year", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.select :event_year_in, Date.today.year-2 .. Date.today.year+3, { prompt: "Any year" }, { id: "select-year", include_blank: true, class: "form-select", multiple: true }  %>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <%= f.submit "Search!", class: "button-orange" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm now creating specific event index pages for particular cities now. So I want to be able to use the other search parameters from my main index page without the name or the address field. So I created a new html erb file with a new scope based off the event model for a particular city:

```html
<div class="container index">
  <div>
    <h1>Dance Events in Austin, Texas!</h1>  
      <br>
    <div class="help-attn">
        <p>All of the search options work together! Create your own search filters to find the events you want!</p>
    </div>
       <%= render 'events/local_search_form' %>
        <br>
          <h5>Currently displaying <%= pluralize(@events.in_austin.count, "event") %>. </h5>
        <br>
  </div>

   <h3>Upcoming Events</h3>
  <div class="event-list-wrapper">
    <% @events.upcoming_events.in_austin.each do |event| %>
      <%= render 'event', event: event %>
    <% end %>
  </div> 

  <h3>Past Events</h3>
  <div class="event-list-wrapper past-event">
    <% @events.past_events.in_austin.each do |event| %>
      <%= render 'event', event: event %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

I also needed to add the `def atx_index` to my event model with the same parameters as the `def index` since in my head they are both index pages, just one has a different scope.

From above you will see that I created a different search form partial to reflect the two fields I don't need anymore, here's the new search form partial.

```html
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
    <div class="formlook">
        <div class="local-search-container">
            z <%= f.hidden_field :address_or_city_or_state_or_country_or_continent_cont_all, value: [""] %>
            <div class="dancestyle">
                <%= f.label "Dance style", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.select(:dance_styles_id_in, DanceStyle.all.pluck(:name, :id), { :include_blank => "All dance styles" }, { class: "form-select", id: "select-dancestyle", multiple: true, placeholder: "Any dance style" }) %>
            </div>
            <div class="eventtype">
                <%= f.label "Event Type", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.select :event_type_id_in, EventType.all.pluck(:name, :id), { :include_blank => "All event types" }, { id: "select-artist", multiple: true, placeholder: "Any event type", class: "form-select" } %>
            </div>
            <div class="month">
                <%= f.label "Month", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.select(:event_month_in, (Date::MONTHNAMES[1..12]), { prompt: "Any month" }, { id: "select-month", :include_blank => "Any month", class: "form-select", multiple: true }) %>
            </div>
            <div class="year">
                <%= f.label "Year", class: "form-label" %>
                <%= f.select :event_year_in, Date.today.year-2 .. Date.today.year+3, { prompt: "Any year" }, { id: "select-year", include_blank: true, class: "form-select", multiple: true }  %>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <%= f.submit "Search!", class: "button-orange" %>
<% end %>
```

So the specific city event index page is displaying properly following the scope but when I use the search I'm redirected to the main event index page with the search parameters that I inputted. I'm not understanding how the two different search form partials are both linked to the main event index page.

How do I get the new search form partial for the specific city index page to display the search results on its corresponding page?

Answer (score 0):

The issue to my redirect form issue was that I need to set the URL of the new form I created, so I was able to get the proper path names from the routes.

My initial implementation though had my configuring the form specifically and since I wanted to reuse the form on multiple pages for the individual local cities, I was lucky to find an old 7 year old SOF article that referred to setting the url in the render line like this:

`<%= render 'events/local_search_form', { url: atx_index_path } %>`

and then calling that url string in the local_search_form like so:

```html
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :url %>
  <%= search_form_for @q, { url: url } do |f| %>
```

and now I can simply change the url path for each html.erb file I create for each individual city! I didn’t know about the local assigns!